Unexpected end of JSON input / Build NextJS / TypeScript
I'm struggling with my NextJS application build.
When building I don't have any clues on what's going on.
Just the random error (Screen 1).
I know that the errors is coming from "types checking" inside the  component, with columns params.
Hope you will highlight me, thanks

(Screen 2) - page.tsx

(Screen 3) - DataTable.tsx

(Screen 4) - Columns.tsx
https://i.sstatic.net/82H0kwnT.png

https://i.sstatic.net/AJot47U8.png

https://i.sstatic.net/DdSkYod4.png

https://i.sstatic.net/GSh8xLQE.png



Please don't post code and error messages a picture but as text

but depending on which node version you have installed, you might suffer from the same issue as in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79196464/react-js-failed-to-compile-unexpected-end-of-json-input-error
